# jss create command is not available in sitecore jss cli version 13

Tags: jss

I'm trying to create new jss app for Sitecore 9.3. I have installed sitecore jss-cli version 13.0. When I try to create new jss app using "jss create" command nothing is happening. where in I'm able create an app using the command "npm init sitecore-jss". It looks like create command itself is not available.
Node version installed: v18.12.1
JSS CLI version: 13.0.0
npm version: 9.1.2

[image: JSS CLI issue]

Comment: It seems it was something to do with Node version. I was having latest node and npm, But JSS 13 uses lower version of node and npm (required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' }). post downgrading the node and npm version. I was able to create and run the jss app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is because of the Node js version over the period of time few dependent packages are deprecated. Therefore it does not support the latest node/npm version.

I tried the below steps and it got resolved:

1. Install node js version 13.14.0
2. Add jss CLI globally using : `npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@13.0.0`
3. `jss create my-jss-app angular --branch release/13.0.0`

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Sumit Helaiya for me installing the node version "10.13.0" helped

Answer (score 1):

As per the Sitecore documentation for JSS, you should run this command before creating the app.

```
npm i @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@<version>
```

And then run the create command like this.

```
jss create my-jss-app angular --branch release/13.0.0
```

And then follow the other steps mentioned in this document.

Refer to this article for more details.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/create-a-jss-app-for-an-older-version-of-sitecore.html

Comment: I do followed the steps but looks like a node version is the issue, after downgrading the node version to "10.13.0", it worked.